# Xml Parsing Defaulting Variable

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am refactoring some project and I ended up an xml, and the xml contains line below:

```
<SchoolLibraryOperations name="UpdateTheLibrary" key="Library/${FLOOR::FIRSTFLOOR}/Book/Update/${updateSessionId}"/>
```

I do not really know the meaning of `FLOOR::FIRSTFLOOR` here. When I am told, it is defaulting the variable to `FIRSTFLOOR` when any variable defined in for `FLOOR.`

Oracle xml parser is being used. When I checked the documentation for Oracle XML parsing, I didnt see anything about `::` . Is there anyone knows how `::` work in here?

Comment: Any regular XML parser will do exactly nothing with the `${ ... }` construct. It has no special meaning in XML and the Oracle docs make no mention of it. To me it looks like a template syntax for a post-processing step.

Comment: @Tomalak so its probably something about the code after its parsed, in the code somewhere its defaulted?

Comment: This would be my guess. `${variable}` is commonly found in as a placeholder in templating engines - could be a standard one or a hand-rolled one, hard to tell. Is there no code you can search for things like `updateSessionId`? (that said, it could also be a pre-processing step, swapping in values before it's handed to an XML parser)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot dig into the code where they are all parsed. But knowing theres no syntax like `::` in default XML is sort of enough for me for now. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Tomalak after digging the docs, I ended up here https://docs.neeveresearch.com/display/TALONDOC/Sending+and+Receiving+Messages#SendingandReceivingMessages-ChannelKeysandTopicResolution , so its not related to XML but the neeveresearch. You were right.